# How to stop unlink images when remove a site or user

Tags: multisite, images, uploads, media, customization

What's the best way to prevent images deleting?.
I have a central cdn site to share images to several sites on wordpress multisite, and by mistake, I have remove a user from the network and all my media files has been deleted.

I think thats enough, hooking a filter to `wp_delete_file` to prevent stop unlink

```
$file = apply_filters( 'wp_delete_file', 'my_custom_wp_deletefile' ); 
my_custom_wp_deletefile() { 
   return false;
}
```

But I don't know if I need anymore.